# detox: tap button only if exists

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, detox

In my test, I would like to simulate a tap in the "cancelUpgrade" button only if it is displayed:

```
it('should be in home menu', async () => {
  await waitFor(element(by.id('cancelUpgrade')))
    .toBeVisible()
    .withTimeout(2000);
  await element(by.id('cancelUpgrade')).tap();
});
```

It returns the expected error `Error: Cannot find UI element.`

https://github.com/wix/detox

Comment: What's "detox"?

Comment: Seems like it's this: https://github.com/wix/detox

Comment: For people who are new here [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434567/2576623) can is quite reusable and good :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap tap in the try/catch block:

```
it('should be in home menu', async () => {
  await waitFor(element(by.id('cancelUpgrade')))
    .toBeVisible()
    .withTimeout(2000);
  try {
    await element(by.id('cancelUpgrade')).tap();
  } catch (e) {}
  // continue your tests
});
```

Not the best way but i think that's what currently possible within detox.

Comment: Can you please explain what your is doing differently from the OP and why your example works as expected?

Comment: Just to give more info on why this solution works. From detox documentation: "NOTE: waitFor will not throw when reaching timeout, instead it will just continue to the next line." So if the button is not available .tap() will throw, and it's silently swallowed by the catch in this case.

Comment: Also, FWIW, you can use the `try/catch` "trick" to place alternate code path in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect we can use this pattern with `toExist`

```
it('should be in home menu', async () => {
  await waitFor(element(by.id('cancelUpgrade')))
    .toBeVisible()
    .withTimeout(2000);
  try {
    await expect(element(by.id('cancelUpgrade'))).toExist();
  } catch (e) {}
  // continue your tests
});
```

And if you don't need to wait:

```
it('should be in home menu', async () => {
  try {
    await expect(element(by.id('cancelUpgrade'))).toExist();
  } catch (e) {}
  // continue your tests
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution but I created a util function called `waitForElement` and it worked.

```
export const sleep = async (milliseconds) =>
   new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));

/**
 * Wait for element to be available in the UI hierarchy
 * @param {Detox.Element} appElement detox element
 * @param {Number} timeout Timeout in milliseconds
 * @param {Number} maxRetries
 * @returns {Object}
 * {
 *   found: <Boolean>, // Determines if element was found
 *   retryCount: <Number> // Number of tries to find the element
 * }
 */
export const waitForElement = async (appElement, timeout, maxRetries = 5) => {
  let found = false;
  let retryCount = 0;

  while (!found && retryCount < maxRetries) {
    try {
      await expect(appElement).toExist();
      found = true;
    } catch (err) {
      retryCount += 1;
      if (retryCount < maxRetries) {
        await sleep(timeout);
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }

  return {found, retryCount};
};
```

Usage example:

```
it('should be in home menu', async () => {
    const cancelUpgradeElement = element(by.id('cancelUpgrade'));
    await waitForElement(cancelUpgradeElement, 2000);
    await cancelUpgradeElement.tap();
});
```